# Acces to MySQL automatic data transfer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vba

I have to pass data from Access database to a MySQL database attached to HeidiSQL automatically every minutes. To do that i put the data into excel files format .xls with vba code every minutes.

After that i get the data from .xls files with a php script to modify data and put them into MySQL DB.

I already have the script that modify and put the data in MySQL from xls.

> The problem is how to call the php script every
> minutes and wait until it finished before doing anything else ?

I'm using windows OS.

Comment: What kind of script? PHP? VBA? Some SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you using windows you can use task scheduler, this [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) might be useful

Comment: I modifiy and clarify my post. I can't use cronjob im using Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule long-running tasks to run from a command line script.
You may try using the

"* * * * * [command] "

making the cronjob definition to run the script you have prepared to pass the data.

Comment: This has already been suggested by another user, and the answer has been given that cronjob does not apply to them. Don't suggest the same solution that someone else has already suggested, it's just pollution.